# Which technology (Spring Roo / Django) to build my 'CMS-like' application on GAE?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, gwt, spring-roo, wcm

I would like to create my company based upon a tourism project (WEB 2.0 / CMS like).

Firstly, I want to argue why I think, in my case, that I should develop it (from scratch, but with a good plateform or tool). Indeed, I think that today (but maybe I am wrong...), some tools (or plateform...) are very powerfull and we can be very productive with it.

Moreover, these requesite 'could' jutify to implement my own software : 
 - my software may interact with other applications (or other tourism database)
 - I need to do an 'inline administration' such as MAGNOLIA (not all CMS have it I think)
 - I have no monney to buy one good CMS doing the work I need (such as Alfresco, or Magnolia or Liferay...) 
 - I think that for a long term project, it could be more rentable to develop it in order to have a better control on its evolution.
 - I would like to use GAE because it is a cheaper and more flexible solution for the hosting (I do not think that all CMS work on it)

Secondly, now, if you agree with me (but if I am wrong about the liscence, or other solution, tell me please), I really like some help about the technologies...I think that **SPRING ROO** is a very good tool to develop my CMS. But maybe I should use **DJANGO** (can you argue about the choice between these 2 solutions to develop my software ?).

My CMS functionalities needed are mainly :
 - versionning of the articles (talking about touristic places...) and a repository for them.
 - a search (Solr is include in Spring Roo)
 - using the AJAX technology (quick refresh)...I would like to use **GWT**
 - permissions (administrator, visitor, contributor, manager...)
 - multi-langage and maybe multi-domain websites (or I should have a big portal that give acces to all countries)
 - a Backend management for the adverts (I am not sur if delegating this task to **dfp** (DoubleClick For Publisher) is a good idea ?
 - User authentication (LDAP)...I do not know if SPRING ROO manage this ?
 - Having simple workflow (such as editing, validating then publishing the article...)
 - Think about Mobile App (**Android**)...so I think that if I choose JAVA, it will be easier to 'translate' on the Android Plateform...

Then, I am sorry if there is a lot of 'topics' in my thread but it is very complicated for me. So I would like to know if, as supposed, I used SPRING ROO + GAE + GWT, so I should use **BIGTABLE** (the Google NoSQL) ?

At last but not least, I have **not** found a website that explain how to create my own CMS...what I want to know is how to do the architecture of the software, because there is a lot of technologies interacting (OSGi, Solr, JPA...) and I do not masterize them, so I would know in what order do I need to process...

For the **security** part, do you think that taking care about the XSS injection is enought ?

To conclude, I know that it is difficult to help me because I ask a lot of things, **but here I am now**...and in order to explain in what context I am, I would like to take the time to learn 'interesting technologies' because if my project fail, I would reconvert myself in an 'expert' of the tool I have learned (ready to spend until 6 month, 24/24, 7/7 :D to create my CMS-LIKE).

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to avoid inserting too much information in your question :) Better throw smaller questions so people answer's are more suitable to your problem.

If you plan to deploy on GAE, well my answer is:

- GWT for web-dev platform (I don't use neither GXT nor SmartGWT)
- Objectify (for persistence on GAE only, kind of vendor lock-in but a good choice)
- Use Google App for business and use their OpenID to handle authentication (will reduce a lot your work stack, and especially security concerns).

Optionally, you could use a framework to assist your presentation layer like GWT-platform which is really great. They also offer a nice command pattern implementation. The framework as it's limitations but the guys working for the project are just great.

Try to stay away from Spring-Roo for production app. I tried a few prototypes, buy going further is hard. At least it was in my experience.

Comment: yes, I heard a lot of people talking 'bad' about Spring Roo. I have not tried it at all, but it seems that the last release is more stable and major bugs have been fixed.

Comment: ok, so, can you tell me, which free ($$$) CMS should I use knowing thet I was seduced by MAGNOLIA :)...

Comment: Well, I don't know Magnolia, but I see it's Java based so any GWT solution is good. I tried the last version of Spring-Roo, it's just not ready for GAE. I was aming GAE and Roo was not very helpful.

Comment: Hi, you may say true, but I am badly surprise...did you try this tutorial : http://code.google.com/intl/fr/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/roo-sts.html ...I just, start to learn GWT today..so I will go step by step...

Comment: Hi, ok I need 3 elements please...can you give me your advice :

Which tecnology for the workflow ? ( ?)
Which technology to manage permissions ? (LDAP ?)
Which technilogy to manage the content repository ? (Jackrabbit ?)

I would like to use Spring Framewrok, so wich compatible technology should you advice me ?

Tkx

Comment: Tried many tutorials for Spring-Roo to deploy on Google App Engine. It works for simple projets but as your complexity grows you regret having used Roo. So you disconnect Roo management.

Comment: As for access control, I use RBAC (but for large env.). So access control is granted by "isAuth()" requests.

Comment: If you plan to deply to GAE check this before choose any technology http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava

Comment: Ok, so you right...ROO could be cool to start the project (Maven + others functionalities) and it should be better to not use after due to the appearing complexities. But, here, it appears that GAE is more my problem because of not supporting all JAVA features. So what shoult I do ? Too complex to develop my own CMS, too expensive to buy a good one (Alfresco...), and I need a good (and cheap) hosting (someone has recommended to me this : http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/ maybe it is a good idea ? Tks a lot ++

Comment: Well, GAE has limitations due to it's underlying datastore. Remember you can ask more questions to include more people, and vote plz :) GAE supports more lib which are not there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478760/what-cms-runs-on-google-app-engine

Comment: Ok, tks, I have recently read the post you have sent me. I need to know if i have to pay to use the Google OpenID (SSO) as you recommended. But I am not already familiar with Stack Overflow forum...I can just add comment under our talks, but is it normal ? Why are you the only person to help me :D ? Tks

Comment: Here is how it goes on stakoverflow: 1- Post a question (as simple and narrow as possible). 2- The question that satisfies you, check it (and usually up vote it). Post as many questions as possible, people will respond newer un-responded questions.

Comment: After many searchs, I just see that your answer is really great...here is exactly what you recommended me [link](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/highly-productive-gwt-rapid-development-with-app-engine-objectify-requestfactory-and-gwt-platform.html)...I have another question...it would be about SEO. Do you know if with GWT I can do my content 'search engine friendly'.... Google has done this : [link](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/) but I just would like to be sure, that it is a good issue to my problem (my site absolutely need to be referenced on the web). Tkx

Comment: Well my best advice is for you to use GWT-Platform :) Theses guys (Phil Beaudoin) are great at what they do. I'm impatiently waiting for their session to be available at the IO2011.3 Check this out: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/CrawlerSupport

Comment: yeah, you are right...I have seen this....so here is the solution of all my 'headaches'....the last one is about the search engine...I would like, at least a tool to help me to have a faceted navigation (features provided by search engines...). What happen is that GAE will have its full text search :   http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/roadmap.html

Comment: but I do not know, if I will be able to plug in this 'search engine' after I have done and organisez all my datastore ? Do you know a full text search on GAE/Objectify... ? Tkx